# How do I change how many contacts to display?

Tags: cms, component

When I make a menu item for com_contacts > All contacts in a list, I want to show just 5 contacts and use pagination for the rest. Where is the parameter for the # of contacts to be displayed?

Answer (score 1):

It should take the "Default List Limit" setting from the Global Configuration. However changing that will also change the list limits for all other extensions as well.